# Impossibility of creating a service control in Vertex AI Search

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, vertex-ai-search

I am looking to set up a serving control to influence and modify the results returned by Vertex AI Search.
I call the url:

```
"https://discoveryengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/global/collections/default_collection/dataStores/DATA_STORE_ID/controls?CONTROL_ID=XXXX"
```

in CURL but I get a 404 Method not found error

I thought it was a rights error but I couldn't resolve it.
Someone would have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues here:

1. [Serving controls is an allowlist-only feature](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/configure-serving-controls#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20create%20serving%20controls%2C%20contact%20your%20Google%20account%20team%20and%20ask%20to%20be%20added%20to%20the%20allowlist%20for%20serving%20controls.). You must have a Google Cloud account team in order to request access at this time.
2. If you have allowlist access, The REST command you're using isn't following the correct format as shown in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/configure-serving-controls#:%7E:text=Run%20the%20following%20curl%20commands%20to%20create%20your%20controls.).

<strike>However, the documentation is also incorrect and the correct URL path should be in this format. (The URL is missing `controlId=`). I'm in the process of fixing the documentation.</strike> Documentation has been fixed.

```
"https://discoveryengine.googleapis.com/v1alpha/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/global/collections/default_collection/dataStores/DATA_STORE_ID/controls?controlId=CONTROL_ID"
```

Comment: Hello Holt and thank you in advance for taking the time to answer me.

I call the correct url (point #2) by adding controlId= so the problem does not come from there.

I also noted point #1 (Serving controls is an allowlist-only feature.) but I don't really understand this specific sentence: You must have a Google Cloud account team in order to request access at this time.

Do I need to contact someone at Google Cloud or the person managing the Google Cloud account I use to give me certain rights (IAM for example)

Comment: This feature is early access for specific Google Cloud customers/businesses. If you or your business don't already have an account team, you can reach out to Google Cloud Sales at this link https://cloud.google.com/contact